# bsearch function in c

Tags: c, qsort, bsearch

If I have two functions:

```
void SortStudents(char *studentList[], size_t studentCount) 
{
    qsort(studentList, sizeof(studentList)/sizeof(studentList[0]), sizeof(studentList[0]), Compare);
}

int Compare(const void *a, const void *b) 
{
    return (strcmp(*(char **)a, *(char **)b));
}
```

That sort and compare using the qsort function, how do I use bsearch to find subsets of my list.  For example, if I have two lists:

- (List A) Bob, Jimmy, Lee, James, Anne
- (List B) Jen, Jon, Lee, James, Steph

How do I search in List B to find those elements in A?

Can you also do a search in List B to find those elements not in A?

Thanks.

Comment: Note: you can't use 'sizeof(studentList)' meaningfully when studentList is a parameter to the function - you will be searching a list of size 1.

Comment: Sorry, can you explain that further?  I'm not quite sure why still.

Comment: Because the type of 'studentList' in the function is 'char **' so the size is the same as the size of a pointer (either 4 or 8 bytes on essentially all machines), and the sizeof(studentList[0]) is the size of 'char *', which is the same size, so the number of elements passed to qsort to be sorted is 1 - which doesn't take long or call any comparators.

Comment: I know that when arrays not used soley with sizeof and & become ptrs to first element. So are you saying that param char *studentlist[] is ptr to array, so also, in my func, sizeof(studentlist) is sizeof (ptr to array), and also sizeof(studentlist[0] is sizeof(first elem of array)? Thanks

Comment: more or less; the parameter 'char *studentList[]' is equivalent to 'char **studentList' (just like you can write `int main(int argc, char *argv[])` or `int main(int argc, char **argv)`), which is subtly different from a pointer to an array, `char *(*array)[40]`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To do a search, you have to use a one-item list as the key parameter to 'bsearch()'.

In context, searching for the entry at `a_list[n]` in `b_list`:

```
 void *found = bsearch(&a_list[n], b_list, b_list, b_size, Compare);
```

So, to find the elements in List B that are in List A, you will do:

- Sort List B (you do not need to sort List A for this part of the exercise unless you want to)
- For each element in List A, search for the item in (the sorted) List B.

And to find the elements in B that are not in A, you will need to sort List A after all and then for each element in List B, see whether the element is in List A using the reversed search.

---

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

static char *a_list[] = { "Bob", "Jimmy", "Lee", "James", "Anne"  };
static char *b_list[] = { "Jen", "Jon",   "Lee", "James", "Steph" };
static size_t a_number = sizeof(a_list)/sizeof(a_list[0]);
static size_t b_number = sizeof(b_list)/sizeof(b_list[0]);

static int Compare(const void *a, const void *b) 
{
    return (strcmp(*(char **)a, *(char **)b));
}

void SortStudents(char *studentList[], size_t studentCount) 
{
    qsort(studentList, studentCount, sizeof(studentList[0]), Compare);
}

static void dump_list(const char *tag, char **list, size_t number)
{
    size_t i;
    printf("%s:\n", tag);
    for (i = 0; i < number; i++)
        printf(" %s%s", list[i], (i == number - 1) ? "" : ",");
    putchar('\n');
}

static char *search_list(char *name, char **list, size_t number)
{
    char **found = bsearch(&name, list, number, sizeof(*list), Compare);
    return((found == 0) ? 0 : *found);
}

static void names_in_list(char **find_list, size_t find_number, char **name_list, size_t name_number)
{
    size_t i;
    for (i = 0; i < find_number; i++)
    {
        char *name = search_list(find_list[i], name_list, name_number);
        if (name != 0)
            printf("Found %s in list at %s\n", find_list[i], name);
    }
}

static void names_not_in_list(char **find_list, size_t find_number, char **name_list, size_t name_number)
{
    size_t i;
    for (i = 0; i < find_number; i++)
    {
        char *name = search_list(find_list[i], name_list, name_number);
        if (name == 0)
            printf("Did not find %s in list\n", find_list[i]);
    }
}

int main(void)
{
    dump_list("Unsorted A list", a_list, a_number);
    dump_list("Unsorted B list", b_list, b_number);
    SortStudents(a_list, a_number);
    SortStudents(b_list, b_number);
    dump_list("Sorted A list", a_list, a_number);
    dump_list("Sorted B list", b_list, b_number);
    dump_list("Searching in B list for people in A list", b_list, b_number);
    names_in_list(a_list, a_number, b_list, b_number);
    dump_list("Searching in A list for people not in B list", a_list, a_number);
    names_not_in_list(b_list, b_number, a_list, a_number);
    return(0);
}
```

---

And the output was:

```
Unsorted A list:
 Bob, Jimmy, Lee, James, Anne
Unsorted B list:
 Jen, Jon, Lee, James, Steph
Sorted A list:
 Anne, Bob, James, Jimmy, Lee
Sorted B list:
 James, Jen, Jon, Lee, Steph
Searching in B list for people in A list:
 James, Jen, Jon, Lee, Steph
Found James in list at James
Found Lee in list at Lee
Searching in A list for people not in B list:
 Anne, Bob, James, Jimmy, Lee
Did not find Jen in list
Did not find Jon in list
Did not find Steph in list
```

Comment: in the bsearch function you listed, is &a_list[n], the same as &a_list?

Comment: No.  `&a_list[n]` is the address of the Nth item in the list; &a_list is the address of the list, which is approximately equivalent to the address of the zeroth item in the list (technically, the type is different, but the address is the same).

Comment: Why do you use char ** found = bsearch, as opposed to just char *?

Comment: @Crystal: Because I want to get the right answer.  If I was searching an array of ints, I would get back an int pointer.  When I'm search an array of 'char pointer', I get back a 'char pointer pointer'.